# How to resolve instances with Castle Windsor that rely on values from the HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm using Web Api with the OWIN pipeline.

## Startup.cs

```
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // extension method to resolve controllers with Windsor.
        app.UseWindsorApi(config, container);
    }
}
```

## MyClassInstaller.cs (IWindsorInstaller)

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) 
{
    container.Register(
        Component.For<IMyClass>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>()
            .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest()
            .DependsOn(new {
                configSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"],
                otherSetting = ???
            }));
}
```

## MyClass.cs & IMyClass.cs

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass {
    private readonly string configSetting;
    private readonly string otherSetting;

    public MyClass(string configSetting, string otherSetting) {
        this.configSetting = configSetting;
        this.otherSetting = otherSetting;
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        // method that uses the settings that were set in the constructor.
    }
}

public interface IMyClass {
    void DoSomething();
}
```

## MyController.cs

```
public class MyController : ApiController {
    private readonly IMyClass myClass;

    public MyController(IMyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync() {
        // uses this.myClass
    }
}
```

Here's where I'm stuck. Whenever an instance of **MyClass** is resolved the value of **otherSetting** needs to be assigned.

The value of **otherSetting** is determined by two things.
1) The **client_id** claims value from the request.
2) An async call to a method that takes the **client_id** as a parameter and returns a string value. Which is what gets set into **otherSetting**

```
public async Task<string> GetOtherSetting(string client_id) {
    return "value";
}
```

I'm not sure where to even begin to get Castle to inject a value based on those two criteria...

**UPDATE:**
I've updated to potatopeelings answer with some minor changes and it seems to be working fine.

```
.DynamicParameters(async (k, p) =>
{
    var fundNameProvider = k.Resolve<IFundNameValueProvider>();
    p["otherSetting"] = await fundNameProvider.GetFundNameAsync();
    k.ReleaseComponent(fundNameProvider);
}))
```

I changed it to an async lambda so I can await the method.
I also called ReleaseComponent as I was under the impression that objects you manually Resolved with Castle you also needed to manually release.

Comment: You're right - if your object is transient and the container has LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy, you must manually release when you manually resolve. Otherwise its optional but its always better to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UsingFactoryMethod` and `DynamicParamters`

First, inject the current claims

```
...
Component.For<ClaimsIdentity>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).LifestylePerWebRequest()
...
```

into a service (`IOtherValueProvider` - PerWebRequest) that has a `GetOtherSetting` method to wait on an async call (i.e. convert the async call to a synchronous call) to get **otherSetting** from the **client_id** extracted from the injected `ClaimsIdentity`

Then use `DynamicParameters` to get the value

```
... register your class ...
.DynamicParameters((kernel, parameters) =>
    {
        parameters["otherSetting"] = kernel.Resolve<IOtherValueProvider>().GetOtherSetting();
    }))
```

Comment: I don't think this will work with an async method GetOtherSetting.

Comment: That's what I thought too when I saw it. I'm actually in the process of coding something up now. Do you have a suggestion for how to do it?

Comment: Instead of trying to inject the othersettings, inject an instance of the IOtherValueProvider. In your code you can then in async methods retrieve the otherSetting.

Comment: I'm still screwing with it, but I think this actually is going to work. I just updated the DynamicProperties to be an async call.

Comment: @Marwijn - sorry, it wasn't that clear in my original version - GetOtherSetting waits on the async call (converting it to a synchronous call) - I've added a clarifying phrase to that part. Cheers!

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer. I updated my question with the actual solution I used.